# Can I use an imported file from FilePicker as a MediaPlayer source

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, filepicker

I am working on an app that plays audio using the MediaPlayer. It works when the audio file to play is already in the Assets folder. However, my goal is to use the [FilePicker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker/2.1.34) plugin for the user to pick a file from their device to be played.

From the FilePicker, I am able to get a path (which seems to be a Uri), like `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/6531`. However, attempting use the MediaPlayer with this path (both as a string and as a Uri) results in `Java.IO.IOException: 'setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000'`.

I'm assuming it's not possible to use the MediaPlayer on a file outside of the Assets folder. So my question becomes is there a way to add an asset to a project's asset folder when a path is provided? Or am I wrong, and is there a way to use the MediaPlayer given the Uri?

Here is the code of the button that handles importing:

```
Button browse = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.browse);
browse.Click += async delegate
{
   var fileImp = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
   if (fileImp != null)
   {
      path = fileImp.FilePath;
   }
};
```

And after sending the path to another class:

```
public void load()
{
   player = new MediaPlayer();

   player.SetDataSource(path);

   player.Prepare();
}
```

This other attempt at setting the data source does not work either, and gets the same error:

```
public void load()
{
   player = new MediaPlayer();

   Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(songFileString);

   player.SetDataSource(Application.Context, uri);

   player.Prepare();
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could it work now ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I haven't had time yet to fully implement the follow-up to your solution, but the error still exists, yes. I believe it has to do with the fact that Xamarin does not have native support for handling Assets from outside of the Assets folder. Instead, my next step is to try and have the program add the chosen file to the Assets folder before playing it.

Answer (score 0):

`content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/6531`

You could try to convert the uri to the file path.

```
string filePath = null;
Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(path);
if (DocumentsContract.IsDocumentUri(this, uri))
{
    string docId = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(uri);
    if (uri.Authority.Equals("com.android.providers.media.documents"))
    {
        string id = docId.Split(":")[1];
        string selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + "=" + id;
        filePath = getfilePath(MediaStore.Video.Media.ExternalContentUri, selection);
    }
    else if (uri.Authority.Equals("com.android.providers.downloads.documents"))
    {
        Android.Net.Uri contentUri = ContentUris.WithAppendedId(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), long.Parse(docId));
        filePath = getfilePath(contentUri, null);
    }
}
else if (uri.Scheme.Equals("content", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    filePath = getfilePath(uri, null);
}
else if (uri.Scheme.Equals("file", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    filePath = uri.Path;
}
```

`getfilePath` method:

```
private string getfilePath(Android.Net.Uri uri, string selection)
{
  string path = null;
  var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, selection, null, null);
  if (cursor != null)
  {
    if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
    {
        path = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data));
    }
    cursor.Close();
  }
  return path;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately in the getFilePath method I get the error `Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/6531'` coming from the `var cursor` line. Upon some research I learned it may be because of the name of the downloads directory, however I tried changing "public_downloads" to "my_downloads" and it still didn't work, as the filePath would just come back as null.

Comment: @mayomatsuda Try to use `getDataColumn` of ths [FileUtils](https://gist.github.com/HBiSoft/15899990b8cd0723c3a894c1636550a8#file-fileutils-java-L148),convert it to C#